# Conditionally import a component in Vue Router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I'd like to conditionally import a component in the vue router. Here is what I have for the moment:

```
children: [
  {
    path: ':option',
    component: () => import('../components/Option1.vue'),
  },
],
```

Depending on what `:option` is, I want to import a different component (`Option1.vue`, `Option2.vue`, etc.). I know I could put several `children` but i actually need the `option` variable in my parent component (I make tests if the route has an option).

How would it be possible to do that?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can load a generic parent component in the path instead: then, in the component access the value of `option` in `this.$router.params` and then conditionally load the desired Option component.

Comment: This can interest me, how would I write it in the Option component?

Comment: `<component v-bind:is=...>` is the way to dynamically load a component.

Comment: Actually it doesn't work because in this "Option.vue" I would have to import all the options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a loader component containing a [dynamic component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) instead of doing conditional routing.  In the loader, you'll conditionally lazy load the option component based on the route param.  Not only is this easier when routing, you also don't have to manually import anything, and only options that are used will be imported.

**Step 1.** Route to the option loader component

*router*

```js
{
  path: ':option',
  component: () => import('../components/OptionLoader.vue'),
}
```

**Step 2.** In that option loader template, use a dynamic component which will be determined by a computed called `optionComponent`:

*OptionLoader.vue*

```html
<template>
  <component :is="optionComponent" />
</template>
```

**Step 3.** Create a computed that lazy loads the current option

*OptionLoader.vue*

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    optionComponent() {
      return () => import(`@/components/Option${this.$route.params.option}.vue`);
    }
  }
}
```

This will load the component called "Option5.vue", for example, when the `option` route param is `5`.  Now you have a lazy loaded option loader and didn't have to manually import each option.

---

**Edit:**  *OP has now indicated that he's using Vue 3.*

#### Vue 3

For Vue 3, change the computed to use `defineAsyncComponent`:

*OptionsLoader.vue*

```js
import { defineAsyncComponent } from "vue";
```

```js
computed: {
  optionComponent() {
    return defineAsyncComponent(() =>
      import(`@/components/Option${this.$route.params.option}.vue`)
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I use this approach for children routes and parent

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that works in VueJS3:

```
<template>
  <component :is="userComponent"/>
</template>

<script>
import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue';
import { useRoute, useRouter } from 'vue-router';

export default {
  computed: {
    userComponent() {
      const route = useRoute();
      const router = useRouter();

      const components = {
        first: 'Option1',
        second: 'Option2',
        third: 'OtherOption',
        fourth: 'DefaultOption',
      };
      if (components[route.params.option]) {
        return defineAsyncComponent(() => import(`./options/${components[route.params.option]}.vue`));
      }
      router.push({ path: `/rubrique/${route.params.parent}`, replace: true });
      return false;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Source: https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/async-components.html
And it's possible to get an error message like this one for the line with "`return`":
`Syntax Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of null`

In that case, it means you probably want to migrate from `babel-eslint` to `@babel/eslint-parser` (source: https://babeljs.io/blog/2020/07/13/the-state-of-babel-eslint#the-present)

Answer (score 0):

Oh this is really cool so I can foreach component in componentlist, and then render the components in a custom order for each page

In theory, you can have a blocks array and load all content in a custom order

```js
let blocks = [
    {'type': 'header', 'blockContent': [headerData]},
    {'type': 'section1', 'blockContent': [headerData]},
    {'type': 'component1', 'blockContent': [componentData]},
    {'type': 'component2', 'blockContent': [componentData]},
    {'type': 'section2', 'blockContent': [headerData]},
    {'type': 'component3', 'blockContent': [componentData]},
    {'type': 'footer', 'blockContent': [footerData]}
]



<div v-for(block in blocks)>
  <div v-if="block.type == 'header'">
    </header-component>
  </div>
  <div v-if="block.type == 'section1'">
    </section1-component>
  </div>
  <div v-if="block.type == 'section2'">
    </section2-component>
  </div>
  <div v-if="block.type == 'component1'">
    </component1-component>
  </div>
  <div v-if="block.type == 'component2'">
    </component2-component>
  </div>
  <div v-if="block.type == 'component3'">
    </component3-component>
  </div>
  <div v-if="block.type == 'footer'">
    </footer-component>
  </div>
</div>
```

This was already answered so I felt free to rant incase someone needs this idea in the future :)