# Return component in beforeEnter in vue router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-router, pinia

I have the following path in my router

```
{
                path: '/Page',
                component: async () => {
                    const isUserLogged = await getUser()
                    const store = useStore()
                    if (userLogged && store.value1) {
                        return import('./pages/PublicPage/PublicPage.vue')
                    } else {
                        return import('./pages/NonPublicPage/NonPublicPage.vue')
                    }
                },
            },
}
```

Every time I enter this path, I need to return a different component depending on the value in the store, but the component is loaded only once.
I tried to rewrite the structure so that it uses beforeEnter as follows:

```
{
path: '/Page',
beforeEnter: async (to, from, next) => {
                    const isUserLogged = await getUser()
                    const store = useStore()
                    if (userLogged && store.value1) {
                            next({
                                component: () => import('./pages/PublicPage/PublicPage.vue'),
                            })
                    } else {
                        next({
                            component: () => import('./pages/NonPublicPage/NonPublicPage.vue'),
                        })
                    }
                },
}
```

But this solution doesn't work. Without using a different path, I need to return a different component depending on the conditions. Is it possible to return a component in beforeEnter in next() or is there another solution to this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditionally import a component in Vue Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65928787/conditionally-import-a-component-in-vue-router)

Comment: Not really, I have to do everything in the router, not as shown - in the component.

Comment: Just conditionally render the content in page component

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend to use a [Dynamic Component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html).

A simple Solution could look like following.

Your Router

```
{
  path: '/Page',
  component: ConditionalPage
}
```

The `ConditionalPage.vue`

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed } from "vue"  
import PublicPage from "./PublicPage.vue"  
import NonPublicPage from "./NonPublicPage.vue"  

const isUserLogged = await getUser()  
const store = useStore()

const component = computed(() => {
  if (userLogged && store.value1) return PublicPage
  return NonPublicPage
})
</script>
 
<template>
  <component :is="component" />
</template>
```

Here is a more detailed example based on your Code.

[Vue SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#__SSR__eNpVUDtuwzAMvQqhJUsioavhFCh6hY5cXINOHUSUINLtYPjupewgTgZB/L4PZ/eRs/+dyDWulb6MWUFIpwy3ji9ndCro3pHHmFNR+Ez2M7G+wVBSBHQ+7LWKgw4Aub77ygyFBli2+YNNHJD7xKLQ72DnJ2TkNmxKjNcSpZhvnZJlAO1jCZpRTN8OYszBZtrwWHBHt4k4xS77qyQ2l/Oq7t4wcw2slVpb5TcW/KhmaUKQoa+eruJTuQSLfJlYx0ieJJ6+S/oTKgaM7lgxFuTFOF8PUg/7ZOGLRF9FLv+ksIcX)